# How to fetch an array of attributes in iOS Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm using CoreData (NSManagedObject, UIManagedDocument) for an iOS app and I was wondering if it is possible to fetch an array of attributes.

For example, suppose I have `Person` entities in my database and each `Person` has an attribute called `income` and a name called `name`. Suppose I have multiple `Person`s in my database.  Is it possible to fetch an array containing all of the incomes for my entire database? (An array with each person's income as an entry). If so, how would I sort the array by their name?

If this is not possible, how would you suggest I go about accomplishing this? I don't want to fetch the entire `Person` entity because there are many other large attributes such as `images` which would take a long time to fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the properties you want this way:

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest new];
fetchRequest.entity = <person entity description>;
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[ @"name", @"income" ];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"name" ascending: YES] ];
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

NSError* error = nil;
NSArray* personsAttributes = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest: fetchRequest error: &error];
```

personsAttributes will look like that:

```
[
    { "name" : "Alfred", "income" : 1000 },
    { "name" : "Birgite", "income" : 2000 },
    …
]
```

Code with ARC & literals. You'll may have to tailor it to your needs and compilation options.